# A figure inside an anchor inside a paragraph: is it legal in HTML5?

Tags: html

According to the HTML5 spec [you can nest block-level elements inside anchors](http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/).

```
<a>
  <article></article>
</a>
```

But it's not legal to nest block-level elements inside paragraphs because `p` tags can only contain inline elements.

So, there's a contradiction here:

```
<p> <!-- block-level; can only contain inline elements -->
  <a> <!-- inline element; can contain block-level elements -->
    <figure></figure> <!-- block-level; can be nested in <a> but not <p> -->
  </a>
</p>
```

Is the above block legal in HTML5?

Comment: I believe it would conform more to the intended use of the `figure` element (and more semantic) to have it outside of the `p` content.  The `figure` element is meant to be accompanying the content rather than part of it.

Comment: Official spec: `figure` "represents a unit of content, optionally with a caption, that is self-contained, that is typically referenced as a single unit from the main flow of the document, and that can be moved away from the main flow of the document without affecting the document’s meaning".  So semantically and according to the specification it shouldn't be nested in a `p` element even if it was allowed by the spec.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> According to the HTML5 spec you can nest block-level elements inside anchors.

Not quite.

[What the spec says](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) is:

> Content model:
>   Transparent, but there must be no interactive content descendant.

*Transparent* means that the element can contain whatever its parent element can contain. Therefore if the parent of the anchor can have block level children, then the anchor can too. If the parent can't, then nor can the anchor.

In your example a paragraph can contain only *Phrasing content*, and this does not include figure elements, so the example is invalid.

Comment: So what about `<a><article><p><a><figure>`? The parent `a` can have block-level elements. Or is it only the direct parent?

Comment: Only the closest *ancestor* is the *parent*. The great-great-grandparent of an element is not the parent of that element.